# FlurryAgent Android

Tags: android, http, flurry

I have made an application on android to read in news stories. Here is the code in my home screen (relating to flurry agent).

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, SessionVariables.flurry_key);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    finish();
}
```

Then when I click the news button. I have this code for flurry agent:

```
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("Member News", true);
    FlurryAgent.onPageView();
```

My application worked for months but all of a sudden the news stories aren't appearing anymore. I am   using greendao and flurry agent apis.

I am getting an error message: 
"FlurryAgent: onStartsession called with duplicate context, use a specific activity or service instead of using a global context"

any help is much appreciated...Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the calls to `FlurryAgent.onStartSession`? Are you passing in an Activity context?

Comment: Like it says - do not use application context, use activity context. BTW this question is about Flurry, you must show the Flurry code, not the lalala-ni code.

Comment: I changed FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, SessionVariables.flurry_key); to FlurryAgent.onStartSession(MainActivity.this, SessionVariables.flurry_key);    Made no difference

Comment: what version of the flurry SDK?